# django rest framework: how to add custom css class to the ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework and I want to add extra css class names to the PostSerializer's fields. This is my code:

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default="New Post", max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'text')
```

A field like `title` will be rendered as:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label >Title</label>
    <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text"  value="" >    
</div>
```

There is already a class `form-control` exist, I want to add another one, how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set custom class for serializer field in your API you should define custom template for the field type and than define serializer field with this custom template.

First create custom template for example for the input field, which is a copy of rest framework's built-in `input.html` with added `{{ style.class }}` next to `form-control`. Place this inside your templates folder, either inside your app's templates folder or project's templates folder.

```
custom_input.html

<div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
  {% if field.label %}
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label {% if style.hide_label %}sr-only{% endif %}">
      {{ field.label }}
    </label>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input name="{{ field.name }}" {% if style.input_type != "file" %}class="form-control {{ style.class }}"{% endif %} type="{{ style.input_type }}" {% if style.placeholder %}placeholder="{{ style.placeholder }}"{% endif %} {% if field.value is not None %}value="{{ field.value }}"{% endif %} {% if style.autofocus and style.input_type != "hidden" %}autofocus{% endif %}>

    {% if field.errors %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <span class="help-block">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

And than declare your serializer with `custom_input.html` and class attribute set to desired classes. In this example `test1` and `test2` classes will be added next to `form-control` class.

```
serializers.py

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    title = serializers.CharField(style={'template': 'your_template_folder/custom_input.html', 'class': 'test1 test2'})

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'text')
```